'async_read_some' reading 0 bytes
Currently, I am using ASIO 1.10.8.
While reading the data, async_read_some is intermittently throwing EOF error with 0 bytes as read. This is observed to be sporadic and for a few websites only (it works most times and reads around 650 bytes of data when successful).
I can see this was fixed in boost — Revision History — Asio 1.10.1 / Boost 1.55, but I'm still facing the same problem.
Does the issue still persist in higher versions of ASIO, even after the fix in 1.10.1?

Perhaps the servers actually close the connections? Have you looked at the server-side to see what happens? Have you use a tool like Wireshark to see the network packages?

I verified server side data and server is writing data correctly(verified the number of bytes written). But during subsequent read, it throws EOF error.

Please show a [mre], I'll also repeat the advice to get Wireshark involved to check where the actual problem lies

Right now the most reasonable explanation send to be that the buffet is full. Note that if the buffet has zero size (no capacity) it is also full for the purpose of reading operations

@sehe Please don't mention buffets just before lunch-time! :-D

I can only comment on boost::asio and my own code, but I've had a connection up for days -- and I know that, because "reconnect on connection loss" is on my list of things to consider doing...

I have to correct myself. I glossed over the "with EOF" and "some websites". Obviously the server is just closing the connection. Which many webservers do, occasionally. It's normal.

@sehe The same website works sometimes; while it throws EOF occasionally. If this is normal, then what do you suggest? trying to reconnect can help?

Not trying to reconnect seems like the option if you don't care about the connection. Of course, whether it's abnormal only depends on the server - but you didn't tell us so we can't think along. But even with high-available servers there can always be a network drop out. Depending on your service level agreements you might chase that, but your software always needs ways to recover.

I am trying to block certain websites from being displayed. But due to EOF error and data read is zero bytes, I am not able to process the data packet and so I am not able to block them. SSL handshake happens successfully but after that the subsequent async_read_some fails. This is frequently happening with a shopping website www.tatacliq.com and gaming site www.cpyskidrow.com. There could be several others but I have observed the issue with these two sites. I will try with the reconnection logic to see if that helps to read the data.

Time to use tcpdump or wireshark to see what the traffic is. Likely you're just being dropped from the server. Also, if the objective is to drop traffic, does it matter whether you can connect? It sounds like it already works. Unless of course, you want to block other sites. Most people are making proxies/tunnels to circumvent blocks anyways. I don't want to know what you're making this for.

Oh by the way, are you properly using SNI? I have a growing suspicion you're just underestimating the complexity of HTTPS servers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

So turns out, with the help of wireshark I found these specific websites (which were throwing EOF error) were using QUIC protocol while the others use TCP. And my code is written to read TCP. Disabling QUIC in the Browser, caused the websites to fallback on TCP and it worked as expected. https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051232032-Problems-with-QUIC-and-Secure-Web-Gateway#:~:text=The%20simplest%20check%20whether%20QUIC,to%20include%20the%20Protocol%20column.
